# Siegel Walfisz Theorem for algebraic number fields

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory, number-fields, prime-number-theorem

Is there a generalization of the Siegel Walfisz to algebraic number fields? This has been done for the prime number theorem in the prime ideal theorem.

Comment: An analogue of of Siegel--Walfisz for Hecke characters can be found in the following paper: Goldstein, Larry Joel: A generalization of the Siegel-Walfisz theorem. Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 149 1970 417–429.